# async await top of javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

the idea is that there are functions gathering api from two sites and sending data down the chain to the last function which then returns the data to app.post to send to client side, but for some reason I keep getting undefined, is there a reason this is not awaiting for the last function?

-- top --

```
app.post('/', async function(req, res) {
    searchText = (req.body.input)
    searchStockx(searchText)
    result = await goatBrow()
    res.send(result)

})
```

---Last function that resolves variable back to top--

```
async function goatBrow(slug){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
     request({
            method: "GET",
            url: "https://www.goat.com/api/v1/product_templates/" + slug + "/show_v2",
            headers: goatGETHeaders
          },
          function(err, res, body){
            let goatSizes = body.availableSizesNewV2
            let goatPic = body.pictureUrl
            goatJoin = {'photo': goatPic, "size": goatSizes,}

            resolve(goatJoin)

            })
      })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Promise` object is `async` so `goatBrow` does not need to be `async` too

```js
async function first() {
    console.log('before goatBrow');
    await goatBrow();
    console.log('after goatBrow');
}


function goatBrow() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
        console.log('before sleep');
        setTimeout(resolve, 8000)
        console.log('after sleep');
    });
}

first();
```